# Example of a summable positive sequence that satisfies a certain condition?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a measure theory problem, and I would like to come up with a sequence that satisfies the following conditions.

A sequence $(a_n)$ whose terms are all strictly positive such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$$ and such that for every $k$, we have $$a_k > \sum_{j=k}^\infty a_j.$$

Can such a sequence exist? If so, then how can I come up with a particular such sequence? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the 2nd sum to start from $k+1$?

Comment: I think you mean $a_k>\sum_{j=k+1} ^{\infty}a_j.$  E.g $a_n=3^{-n}.$ Or did you want the reverse inequality ? (E.g. $a_n=1/(n\sqrt n).$)

Comment: Yes, starting at k+1, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n = \frac{1}{n^n}$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ and $a_k > \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty a_j$. Both inequalities can be shown with the help of the geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition , any set with measure zero will suffice I think.

Take an example of the Cantor set.